# restcomm HLR and MSC configuration issue

Tags: restcomm, sctp, ss7

Could you please help me to configure the ss7 stack for HLR and MSC
we are using Restcomm-smsc-7.1.71

How to distinguish HLR associations and MSC associations in order to send separately SRI to HLR and forward-sm to MSC ?
How should i configure the ss7 stack so we can have the result described in the attached sequence diagram ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]